# Using Require.js' async attribute with Webix (Client side framework)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, requirejs, webix

I've used Webix to build my entire web application, so it's client-side heavy.  Am I right in assuming that I should NOT use require.js async attribute when requiring modules?

So instead of using data-main, I'll create a require.config for each page?

Comment: What async attribute? RequireJS does not define an async attribute. There's an HTML attribute named async but that's not primarily a RequireJS thing? Do you mean `data-main` everywhere you mention  an attribute in your question?

Comment: The documentation states that using data-main means the dependencies load asynchronously - that's the attribute I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you've made the inference that using `data-main` makes RequireJS operate asynchronously. But that's not the case at all. Using or not using `data-main` makes no difference: RequireJS will load your modules asynchronously. That's always the case when you use RequireJS in the browser. Even when you see code like this:

```
define(function (require) {
  var foo = require("foo");
  [...]
});
```

This is silently converted to an asynchronous form: RequireJS analyses the code in the callback, pulls out the dependencies, loads them asynchronously and then gives control to the callback. By that time, the `require` calls are just lookups in a table but the modules were loaded beforehand, asynchronously.

The exception to "RequireJS loads modules asynchronously" is if you use RequireJS in Node. When you use it in node, you can load modules synchronously. But `data-main` is not a factor there.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Yes, I thought you could bypass the dependencies loading asynchronously by not using data-main ( http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html ). So when I do: `require( ["./common"], function() {
            require(["webix", "tinymce"]}}` does this not mean that .common will be loaded first and then webix and tinymce will be loaded next, in this order?